# Making grid item into link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating my first website and I tried to use `display: grid` which I've recently studied. Everything went smoothly but there's one thing that I'm stuck on:

[image]

So my aim is to make the entire box, into a link, such as:

[image]

```css
.grid-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 22%);
  grid-template-rows: 37.39px repeat(6, 90px);
  grid-gap: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-category {
  background-image: url('../imgs/backgroundgood.png');
  background-repeat: round;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 220%;
}

.grid-item {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3b3d49;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  justify-self: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.grid-container .grid-item .text {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container .useless {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-category">Equipment</div>
  <div class="grid-category">Weapons</div>
  <div class="grid-category">Ammunition</div>
  <div class="grid-category">Miscellaneous</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item1">
    <div class="text">Helmet</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item2">
    <div class="text">Rod</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item3">
    <div class="text">Arrow</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item4">
    <div class="text">Necklace</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item5">
    <div class="text">Armor</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item6">
    <div class="text">Wand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item7">
    <div class="text">Bolt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item8">
    <div class="text">Ring</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item9">
    <div class="text">Legs</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item10">
    <div class="text">Axe</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item11">
    <div class="text">Distance</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item12">
    <div class="text">Backpack</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item13">
    <div class="text">Boots</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item14">
    <div class="text">Club</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item15">
    <div class="text">Spellbook</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item16">
    <div class="text">Sword</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item17">
    <div class="text">Shield</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you got `position: absolute` *and* `position: relative` in the `.grid-item` declaration? The first (`absolute`) is overwritten by the second (`relative`), and since you're not moving them anywhere you don't need `relative` (and `absolute` would complicate things unnecessarily by taking the item(s) out of the flow of the document. This is entirely irrelevant to your problem, of course, but I'd suggest trimming the accumulated cruft from the CSS certainly if you're posting your code looking for help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `<div class="grid-item grid-item1">` by `<a href="linkOr#id" class="grid-item grid-item1">`.

You can remove the link style with :

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

Also, instead of using 2 classes like `grid-item grid-item1`, you could only use `grid-itemX` and select element starting with `grid-idem` with `[class^="grid-item"]`.

If you only have one `grid-item1` you could use an `id` instead and select it by the same way : `[id^="grid-item"]`

```css
[id^="grid-item"]{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#grid-item2{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-item1"></div>
<div id="grid-item2"></div>
<div id="grid-item3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.grid-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 22%);
  grid-template-rows: 37.39px repeat(6, 90px);
  grid-gap: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-category {
  background-image: url('../imgs/backgroundgood.png');
  background-repeat: round;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 220%;
}

.grid-item {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3b3d49;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  justify-self: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.grid-item a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  color: black;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}

.grid-container .grid-item .text {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-container .useless {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-category">Equipment</div>
  <div class="grid-category">Weapons</div>
  <div class="grid-category">Ammunition</div>
  <div class="grid-category">Miscellaneous</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item1">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Helmet</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item2">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Rod</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item3">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Arrow</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item4">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Necklace</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item5">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Armor</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item6">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Wand</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item7">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Bolt</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item8">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Ring</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item9">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Legs</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item10">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Axe</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item11">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Distance</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item12">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Backpack</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item13">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Boots</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item14">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Club</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item15">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Spellbook</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item16">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Sword</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item17">
    <a href="#"><div class="text">Shield</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
  <div class="grid-item useless"></div>
</div>
```